# How can I set the favicon while using expressjs 4 and webpack with SSR enabled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express, webpack

so I am trying to update the favicon on my React-ts website. I have SSR setup and it uses express 4.17.1 for the server side.

the issue I'm encountering is that the favicon is set in my client.ejs template file as `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

However once the client and server builds the favicon.ico is not included in the /dist folder so there is no favicon to reference. I have tried manually adding it to the dist folder but I am still getting a 404 resource not found when trying to load the favicon.ico.

I have tried adding the file to the express.static and have also tried setting the favicon under HtmlWebpackPlugin but still no success.

I have seen lots of tutorials online for express favicons and react/webpack favicons but none that have both of the technologies working together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update: Solution!**

What I had to do was set the response options and setup a route that serves the .ico file.

So I set a constant that had my options for .ico files. I have my favicon.ico file located in my static folder at the root of the project.

```
const icoOptions = {
  root: path.join(__dirname + '/../static/'),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'
  }
};
```

Then I setup the express route to serve the file when favicon.ico is requested.

```
server.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => (
  res.status(200).sendFile('favicon.ico', icoOptions)
));
```

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question in the box below. Answers should not be edited into the question